# How to better optimize the integral of this function

Tags: optimization, definite-integrals

Hi so i'm currently working on approximating the integral of this function by taking the summation of the integral at root intervals;

$$ \int_{2.92}^{4.435} sin(100 \sqrt{x^2 + 31364}) $$

by dividing $$ \frac{( 4.435 - 2.92)}{1.5707} $$ , I get 0.96353 but the real integral is 0.953728, how to better optimize it or so to say how to better calculate the area of a such waves without taking any points from the functions at such intervals?

note: 1.5707 is the constant of relativity of $$ \frac{1}{\int_0^1 sin(pi x)} $$

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing exactly, but maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration) is what you are looking for?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah true actually you are right, how do I optimize it though.

Comment: @Klaus I'm actually trying to avoid having to take points from the function.